# Primefaces datatable multiple rows

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I have object of document which contains object of employee1 and employee2. I want to display all employes from list of documents. so:

```
<p:dataTable id="search" var="doc"
     value="{cc.attrs.controller.list}"
     selection="#{cc.attrs.controller.selected}"
     selectionMode="single"
     rowKey="#{doc.id}">

  <p:row>
      <p:column>doc.info</p:column
      <p:column>doc.employee1.name</p:column>
  </p:row>
  <p:row>
      <p:column>doc.info</p:column
      <p:column>doc.employee2.name</p:column>
  </p:row>

</p:datatable>
```

With that i dont see any records -..- .(Important that i need to have oportunity to select rows and send them to bean)

i tried smth like that, that was so close, but i dont know why subtable dont have any property for selected row... :

```
<p:dataTable id="search" var="doc"
     value="{cc.attrs.controller.list}"
     selection="#{cc.attrs.controller.selected}"
     selectionMode="single"
     rowKey="#{doc.id}">

<p:subtable var="person" value="doc.getListOfEmployyes()" >
  <p:row>
      <p:column>doc.info</p:column>
      <p:column>person.name</p:column>
  </p:row>
</sub:table>
</p:datatable>
```

Important also is that i cant just simple put employes list in datatable cause thoose rows need also info about documents

Answer (score 0):

For select multiple row in datatable, you should change `selectionMode="single"` to `selectionMode="multiple"` and be sure your selection value is a list.

Full exemple here : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionMultiple.jsf

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how to send selected row object from subtable. Selected value from datatable works fine, but why cant i send selection from subtable, there isnt any selection property or so.